# Acumatica Screens in Wordpress iFrame

Tags: wordpress, acumatica

Does anyone know how to get Acumatica screens to be embedded in an iFrame in a wordpress site? When embedding an Acumatica screen in wordpress - I see the login screen however - after successful login I receive a refused to connect error.

I tried modifying the X-Frame in the web.config file - however still no difference after login. Does anyone know what changes need to be made on the Acumatica site to allow this? Or is it possibly a change that needs to happen in wordpress?

I realize that we should look at integrating the SSO but conceptually would think that the iFrames would work with or without SSO being setup yet or am I wrong in that assumption?

Comment: SSO not required, you are correct. I suspect login cookie is blocked by same-site policy.

Answer (score 1):

the answer provided by Hugues is very valid, but in the scope of Same Site Cookies.
With iFrame you would generally get following exception:

> The loading of “https://yoursite.acumatica.com/Main?HideScript=On” in a frame is denied by “X-Frame-Options“ directive set to “SAMEORIGIN“.

For a while solution was to add an explicit header X-Frame-Options and in ALLOW-FROM specify an uri to the site you would like to allow to open Acumatica in iFrame, this however is now outdated: [X-Frame-Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options)

Currently suggested way would be to use frame-ancestors directive of the Content-Security-Policy ([frame-ancestors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/frame-ancestors))

For applications that run on IIS, like Acumatica, it is done by finding in web.config

`<httpProtocol>`
   `<customHeaders>`

`...`

And modify and add to this clause line like following example:

```
<add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="frame-ancestors 'self' https://my.site1.com *.site2.net http://localhost:82" />
```

This is just a syntax example that will allow the Acumatica to be open in iFrame on **same domain**, on **my.site1.com**, wildcard for **all subdomains on site2.net** and on even on the **site deployed locally** on the server that listens 82 port. Please use last one (http://localhost:82) only for testing purposes.

So the end result in your web.config should look similar to that block (based on SalesDemo deployment):

```
<httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
        <add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="frame-ancestors 'self' https://yourWordPressUri" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
```

Hope this is helping

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are running into a same-site cookie policy error. If the issue was cross site scripting error you wouldn't see the login page.

Same site cookie policy can be disabled in the web config file:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/samesite/system-web-samesite#using-samesite-in-aspnet-472-and-48

Change the web.config file settings as follows:

**Step 1**: Open the web.config file, which is located in the application instance folder.

**Step 2**: Find the <system.web> section and add the following line to this section:

Note! The first occurrence of <system.web> located in the < location > tag is not the needed section.

**Step 3**: Add the text highlighted in bold to the following lines:

<formsAuth loginUrl="Frames/Login.aspx" timeout="60" **requireSSL="true"** />

<sessionState  **cookieSameSite="None"** cookieless="UseCookies" mode="Custom" customProvider="PXSessionStateStore" timeout="60" sessionIDManagerType="PX.Owin.SessionIdManager, PX.Owin">

Comment: This samesite cookie policy is a new behavior introduced by Google in their Chrome browser (other browsers followed, many being based on Chrome engine): https://blog.chromium.org/2019/10/developers-get-ready-for-new.html